# LookupRows error

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, lookup

Once I try to do a preview of the email the next error appears:

> The Data Extension name for a LookupRows function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist.
>    Data Extension Name: Registered_Fam_Members
>    Function Call: LookupRows("Registered_Fam_Members","PersonContactId",_subscriberkey)
>    Parameter Name: DataExtensionName
>    Parameter Ordinal: 1

That Data Extension exists and the AMPScript code I am using is
`%%=LookupRows("Registered_Fam_Members","PersonContactId",_subscriberkey)=%%`

The Data Extension that is being used as sendable is a Standard one.

Do you know what this issue could be related with?

Comment: I would check the spelling or spacing on your DE. From the error it sounds like the name you provided and the name of the DE in SFMC are different. You could also check to see if it is a shared DE. If so, you will need to use the `ent.` prefix.  e.g. `ent.Registered_Fam_Members`

Comment: Hi @Gortonington that was exactly the error. I've added the ENT. prefix and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Moved into an answer for easy reference from comments***

---

I would check the spelling or spacing on your DE. From the error it sounds like the name you provided and the name of the DE in SFMC are different.

You could also check to see if it is a shared DE. If so, you will need to use the `ent.` prefix. e.g. `ent.Registered_Fam_Members`

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is possible, and LookUpRows is most possibly the right function to use. However, can you please share the AmpScript you have produced so far, and what issues you are facing? Also:

- Are you working in a single BU environment, or do you have a
  hierarchy of BUs?
- Are you using a single-org or multi-org connector?
- Which synced DE do you want to retrieve data from?
- What field do you use for lookup?

Please see [this article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions here of SFSE.